# What is wrong with my "If Statement" in line 44 and my addition to variable statement in line 37?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech

I am currently making the rough outline for a voice controller so I can stop designing parts, but even while making the rough outline I ran into some issues with my rusty skill level in if statement and syntax of variable addition. The specific error is that the program exits out after the first time I ask the script how its doing rather than continuing to run like it should if I remove the line with the variable addition along with the chunk about the differed statement that replaces the old "how are you" after it being asked once.

```
from time import ctime
import time
import os
import pyttsx3
import random


repetitionsocial1=0

numberList = ["Thanks for asking. But I am a computer","222","I eat poop","444","555"]

def recordAudio():
    # Record Audio
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print("Say something!")
     audio = r.listen(source)

    # Speech recognition using Google Speech Recognition
    data = ""
    try:
        # Uses the default API key
        # To use another API key: `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Offline Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Offline Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data

def jarvis(data):
    global repetitionsocial1
    if "how are you" in data and repetitionsocial1==0 :
        repetitionsocial1=repetitionsocial1+1
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say("What answer do you expect. I am a Computer?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        
        

    if "how are you" in data and repetitionsocial1>=0:
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say("I am still fine, but again, I am a computer. You have asked me this"+str(repetitionsocial1)+"times")
        engine.runAndWait()

    if "what time is it" in data:
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(ctime())
        engine.runAndWait()

   # if "where is" in data:
    #    data = data.split(" ")
     #   location = data[2]
      #  speak("Hold on Frank, I will show you where " + location + " is.")
       # os.system("chromium-browser https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location + "/&amp;")

# initialization
time.sleep(2)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hi Frank, what can I do for you?")
engine.runAndWait()

while 1:
    data = recordAudio()
    jarvis(data)
```

Comment: Also. Forgive my immaturity in the "I eat Poop" random string selection towards the top, I was very frustrated and hearing a machine say that relieved a little bit of stress :P

Comment: Thanks but I already tried running it from the terminal. I will try double clicking as you suggested :) *a few minutes later* So running it via execution doesn't work but I narrowed the problem to line 37, it doesn't seem to be able to get past that if statement but will still speak the text.

Comment: Which statements are you asking about? There are no line numbers.

Comment: @Barmar OP's line numbers are off by one; they are referring to `repetitionsocial1=repetitionsocial1+1` and `if "how are you" in data and repetitionsocial1>=0:`.

Comment: No errors. That is correct. Otherwise this would be a lot easier to solve. It just gets stuck on the if statement containing the repetitionsocial1=repetitionsocial1+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two snippets.

```
    if "how are you" in data and repetitionsocial1==0 :
        repetitionsocial1=repetitionsocial1+1
        ...
    if "how are you" in data and repetitionsocial1>=0:
        ...
```

when the first condition is true, it adds 1 to `repetitionsocial1`, so now that variable contains `1`. Therefore, the second condition will also be true, because `1>=0`.

You should use `elif` when you have mutually exclusive conditions, and don't want to consider the variable changes that occurred as a result of the first condition.

Comment: Awesome! I will try that.

Comment: Thank you it worked! once the buffer wears off I will declare this the solution :)